# if else logic | pyramid error

Tags: c, if-statement, cs50

I'm trying to build a c program that prints a right aligned pyramid ie:

```
   ## 
  ### 
 #### 
#####
```

I thought about approaching this using an if-else logic to test the user input. However, when I run my code it keeps giving me this error and also doesn't show the error when the input is not valid.

```
mario.c:25:2: else error: expected '}'
}
 ^
mario.c:7:1: note: to match this '{'
{
```

Example code below:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main (void)
{
    int height;
    height = get_int("Enter a number between 0 and 23: "); // keep prompting user for valid input'

    if (height > 0 || height < 23) {
        for ( int levels= 1 ; levels <= height; levels++) {
            for (int spaces = height-levels; spaces > 0; spaces--){
                printf (" ");
            }
            for (int hash = 1; hash <= levels+1; hash++){
                printf ("#");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        else 
        {
            height = get_int("Please try again: ");
        }

    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `else` --> `} else`  Suggest using an auto formatter for your code.  Life is too short for manual formatting.  Much easier to see `{}` imbalance.

Comment: Whenever the compiler complains about opening or closing brackets or parentheses, always count them first. Try to match opening brackets to closing brackets. See if they make sense.

Comment: You first for loop is not closed.

Comment: You seem to have an else after a for loop. for/else is not a supported construct.

Comment: Thanks so much! Fixed the formatting issues, but now when I run the program and input -5 my else statement doesn't run. Also, I tested with height = 24 and it displayed all the stars. Am I missing something in my logic?

    else
    {
     height = get_int ("invalid input try again: ");
    }

Comment: @AnnetteLin Look carefully. This is because your condition `(height > 0 || height < 23)` holds *true* for both `-5` and `24`. **Hint**: Get rid of the `||`

Answer (score 2):

Here in line `if (height > 0 || height < 23)` you are currently using `||` . Since you want both the conditions to be true *simultaneously*, you should use `&&` instead of `||`.

Condition should be `if (height > 0 && height < 23)`

Answer (score 1):

The `else` is not at the right level:

You have:

```
if (...)
{
    for (...) 
    {
       ...
    } 
    else  
    { 
        ***
    }
}


if (...)
{
    for (...) 
    {
       ...
    }
} 
else  
{ 
    ***
}
```

So in your original code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int height;
    height = get_int("Enter a number between 0 and 23: "); // keep prompting user for valid input'

    /* as pointed by Rajeev Singh, the following || should be a && */
    if (height > 0 || height < 23) {
        for ( int levels= 1 ; levels <= height; levels++) {
            for (int spaces = height-levels; spaces > 0; spaces--){
                printf (" ");
            }
            for (int hash = 1; hash <= levels+1; hash++){
                printf ("#");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        height = get_int("Please try again: ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```